# Fadein and Fadeout for blockquotes

Tags: text, fadein, fadeout

I need some assistance with creating a fadin and fadout for several blockquotes. I reviewed a bunch of jquery codes, but can't seem to find one.

i-MediaSource

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

`$('#element-id').fadeIn();`